# How can I filter the contents in the TABLE panel?

Tags: grafana

So is there a way to filter what Grafana shows in a TABLE type of metric?

My issue is that the table returns values which are really really long like a FQDN but for an Azure resource.

It is absolutely unreadable, so I actually want to parse the output with regex or something, to show me only the specific part. At least a line break would suffice.

The row field in the table is something like

```
azure:///subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-4a5b-81ee-04ea1368a7db/resourceGroups/mc_wintermute_wintermute_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/axxxxxxxxvmss/virtualMachines/13
```

I only need the

```
subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-4a5b-81ee-04ea1368a7db/
```

It is easier to view it than explain, a
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02PK4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a VALUE MAPPING section in the table parameters, which accepts regular expressions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).